# get path to an included file on Classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic, path

I have a file that is being included, in that file there's  
Server.MapPath('../_data") which doesn't work 
since that file included is not in the same Server.MapPath as the file executed. 
any Idea of how I can get the included file's path?

To clarify the situation, I added a picture
[image]

As you can see, I'm including a file from one site to the other 
(no other choice there), so that the server.mappath is intended to be different, though 
the result is that on the included file I get the mappath of the executed file.

Comment: How are you including the other file? SSI? Server.Execute?

Answer (score 0):

You should better use relative paths.

Relative paths start with `/` which means start from the root of the site..

Comment: actually, I AM using a relative path, the thing is , I'm using SaveToFile server.mappath("../data") and it tries to save on the path EXECUTEDFILESERVER/data instead of the INCLUDEDFILESERVER/data (the included file is in another directory, and should return a different mappath) http://imgur.com/Ues2e.png

Comment: @Asaf, hmmm i do not think you can do it, if you include from another site.. the running site would not have access to the other one.. Maybe you could create some sort of service that you can query with an `MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP` request, in order to get the final data from that server..

Comment: oh the including of the file is possible, and it does work... because the folder structure is such to let me access it through ../../site2...... so that's not the issue

Comment: what are you doing with the included file ? if it is self-contained, and it just runs some code and creates output, your could perhaps use the `server.execute` method